# When using Mapbox, is it possible to scroll within a limited area?

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I am using Mapbox_ios_sdk library

Can the scroll range be limited based on a specific location on the map?

For example x-100m to x+100m & y-100m to y + 100m (diameter 200m)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you’re looking for is `maxBounds` and [`setMaxBounds`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map%23setmaxbounds)

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<your access token here>';
// Set bounds to New York, New York
var bounds = [
[-74.04728500751165, 40.68392799015035], // Southwest coordinates
[-73.91058699000139, 40.87764500765852] // Northeast coordinates
];
 
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
center: [-73.9978, 40.7209],
zoom: 13,
maxBounds: bounds // Sets bounds as max
});
```

You have the [full sample here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/restrict-bounds/)

Comment: There is something I missed on the question I wanted an answer on the iOS sdk. But thanks I found the bounds keyword in the answer and implemented it with that content.

Comment: Good to know it was a good clue, the different SDKs in Mapbox used to have a very similar naming convention and concepts in each platform.

Comment: Yes! Again, I learned the importance of naming conventions! and thanks your answer